# "Faster" Arduino bootloader

Tags: arduino, bootloader

The Arduino bootloader has a wait-time to facilitate "sketch" (code) uploading; this causes a delay of a couple of seconds before the start of the main code.

I would like to modify the bootloader file (specifically for the Arduino Mega) so as to reduce this time to **less than 1000 milliseconds** at most.

I am unsure how to get started on this -- Could someone point me in the correct direction?

(Note: I am aware that I can instead directly upload only the hex file corresponding to my firmware, but in this case, I would like to maintain the bootloader.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an overview of the bootloader take a look at the [Bootloader Development](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Bootloader) page.

The actual source code is available and can be browsed [here](http://code.google.com/p/arduino/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fhardware%2Farduino%2Fbootloaders). To modify the wait time (or the behaviour of the waiting) take a look at the [ATmegaBOOT.c](http://code.google.com/p/arduino/source/browse/trunk/hardware/arduino/bootloaders/atmega/ATmegaBOOT_168.c) file.

In line 91 is `MAX_ERROR_COUNT` defined and used to determine when to start the actual application on your arduino. To decrease the waittime, I would start by setting `MAX_ERROR_COUNT` to a lower value.

---

After you posted your comment I had another look at the source code.

At line 433 the "forever loop" is startet and in line 436 the function `getch()` is called.
In this function there is another loop, that checks for a received character. If no character is received within a given timespan the application code is getting called.
The duration of the timespan is determined by `MAX_TIME_COUNT`.

So changing `MAX_TIME_COUNT` seems to be more suitable then changing `MAX_ERROR_COUNT`.

Comment: Perhaps also relevant in the same file is the line of code stating the following? Although it seems to be commented out and refers to the Makefile: **#define MAX_TIME_COUNT (F_CPU>>4)**

Comment: @Inga - You are right! I updated my answer.